# Exiting loop to early or only taking one of a value if its repeated in R

Tags: r, loops

The following is some syntax relating to the problem I want to solve, but a more simplified version.

Say I want to take all the values from one matrix and find if they exist in a specific column of another matrix then from there add them to an empty list.

So:

```
mat1 <- c(1,2,3)
mat2 <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2,2,2,4,21,5153,15315,21,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2314,1,1,1,1,1), nrow =6, ncol =4, byrow = TRUE)

i = 1
j = 1
list_final <- c()
while(i < length(mat1)+1){
    if(mat2[j,2] <- mat1[i]){
        list_final[j] <- mat2[j,2]
        #print(list_final) 
    j=j+1
    }
    i = i+1
}
```

Following running this, the list `list_final` is identical to `mat1`, but I want it to display:

```
[1] 1 2 3 2 2 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just as a follow up, is it better practise to sort it during the loop or after?

ie have an additional line after the list has been appended doing the following:

`[1] 1 2 3 2 2 1` to `[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3`

I am also trying to improve my 'elegance' where possible. Is there a way I can make this code more attractive/efficient rather than requiring two loops...

Comment: What is this line `if(mat2[j,2] <- mat1[i])` supposed to achieve? You're replacing the value of `mat2[j, 2]` with `mat1[i]`, is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: That must be where my misunderstanding arises... the question I am asking, in plain terms, is... if this value in mat2 is equal to that of mat1 then store in the master list, otherwise ignore and next j

Comment: OK, it looks like you mixed up your operators then. `<-` does assignment in R, to test for equality you use `==`. I don't think changing will fully fix your problem, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command will tell you which values in mat1 are also in the first column of mat2:

```
mat1[which(mat1 %in% mat2[,1])]
```

and so with this loop you will go over all columns of mat2

```
for (i in 1:NCOL(mat2))
    list_final<-c(list_final,mat1[which(mat1 %in% mat2[,i])])
```

if you want to sort

```
sort(list_final)
```

I didn't see any 3's in mat2.

Comment: Nice! Not exactly what I wanted but definitely gave me enough to figure it out. Just if you're interested... `mat1 <- c(1,2,3)
mat2 <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2,2,2,4,21,5153,15315,21,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2314,1,1,1,1,1), nrow =6, ncol =4, byrow = TRUE)

list_final <- c()
for (i in 1:NROW(mat2))
  list_final<-sort(c(list_final,which(mat1 %in% mat2[i,2])))
  
print(list_final)`

Comment: it may be the case that the loop is not necessary if you are interested in the second column only, mat1[which(mat1 %in% mat2[,2])], and note the subsetting that needs to be done on mat1. You need mat1[which(mat1 %in% mat2[,2])], not only which(mat1 %in% mat2[,2]). The latter gives you the positions in the array, not the values of the array. Try with different mat1 to see the difference.

Comment: Im interested in taking all those values in the second column and matching their corresponding values in the 3rd and 4th columns. Now that you mention it, avoiding a loop would be much more efficient, at the moment I have made multiple lists and appended them to form this subset containing the 3rd and 4th column elements. Using your method could one make a subset that contains the corresponding elements... Ie in the example we'd have a subset containing `[1] 1,4,2,2314,1 [2] 2,21,2,1,1`